# insert a related list from a indirect relationship

Tags: relationships, related-list, childrelationship

I have an Account object, a related (master detail) contact object and a custom object Automobile__c that has a lookup to the contact. I would like to display the related Automobile__c records on the Account object as a related list where the Account is the parent of the contact record to which the Autombile__c record is related to.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce doesnot allow indirect relationship objects to be displayed on Page layouts.

Workaround is, create a look relationship from `Automobile__c` to `Account` and Update this `Account` lookup field based on the AccountId of the Contact.

i.e.

```
Contact con = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact LIMIT 1];

Automobile__c aut = new Automobile__c();
aut.contact__c = con.Id;
aut.Account__c = con.AccountId;
insert aut;
```

Or, through the process builder you can update account lookup.

Make sure Account Lookup field will not be displayed on the Automobile page layout.

Comment: yep, I was on that track, I'll do it through PB, thanks Santa!